# “ Exception from HRESULT: 0x8107054A ” when activating wsp on Office365 Sandbox Solution

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, wsp, sandbox-solution

I am uploading my wsp file and when I'm trying to activate it getting this error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8107054A
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so this is posted as answer.

You have to analyze the ULS-logs concerning the given correlation ID.

Vardhaman Deshpande has put togehter a great article on this on his blog 
http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/view-tenant-uls-logs-in-sharepoint.html

It's merely based on using the and namespace **Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration** and the class **TenantLog**.

Best of luck
Ben